# @Value Annotation does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-boot

I am using spring application, where i am trying to load a property from properties file using @Value annotation , but variable is always null.

Here is the Code where i am using Annotated variable:

```
@Service
public class RulesEngineServiceImpl implements IRulesEngineService {
 @Value("${display.property}") static String displayProperty;
 @Value("${return.enabled}") static boolean returnEnabled;
 @Value("${return.type}") static String returnType;
 @Value("${immediaterpi}") static boolean immediaterpi;

 private static Rule getDefaultRule() {
    LOG.info("applying default rule displayProperty ="+displayProperty+"|  returnEnabled="+returnEnabled+"| returnType="+returnType+" | immediaterpi="+immediaterpi);
    Rule rule = new Rule();
    rule.setName("DEFAULT_RULE");
    rule.setDisplayProperty(DisplayProperty.valueOf(displayProperty));
    ActionProperty actionProperty = new ActionProperty();
    ReturnActionVO returnAction = new ReturnActionVO(returnEnabled, returnType, immediaterpi);
    actionProperty.setActions(JSONUtils.writeJson(returnAction));
    rule.setActionProperty(actionProperty);
    return rule;
 }
}
```

Here is the properties file named application.prop where these are defined:

```
display.property=xzc
return.enabled=false
return.type=""
immediaterpi=false
```

I have provided reference to this file here:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.prop")})
public class PieApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{

 @Bean
 public PieServletContextListener pieServletContextListener() {
    return new PieServletContextListener();
 } 

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(PieApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```

But when i call this the method `getDefaultRule()` from some other code, it does not load the variables like `displayProperty`
And prints the log as below:

```
applying default rule displayProperty =null|  returnEnabled=false| returnType=null | immediaterpi=false
```

Please Advice.

**Edit:** 
Below is the code change in case i make them non-static

```
@Value("${display.property}")  String displayProperty;
@Value("${return.enabled}") boolean returnEnabled;
@Value("${return.type}")  String returnType;
@Value("${immediaterpi}")  boolean immediaterpi;

private static Rule getDefaultRule() {
    RulesEngineServiceImpl rulesEngineService = new RulesEngineServiceImpl();

    LOG.info("applying default rule displayProperty ="+rulesEngineService.displayProperty+"|  returnEnabled="+rulesEngineService.returnEnabled+"| returnType="+rulesEngineService.returnType+" | immediaterpi="+rulesEngineService.immediaterpi);
    Rule rule = new Rule();
    rule.setName("DEFAULT_RULE");
    rule.setDisplayProperty(DisplayProperty.valueOf(rulesEngineService.displayProperty));
    ActionProperty actionProperty = new ActionProperty();
    ReturnActionVO returnAction = new ReturnActionVO(rulesEngineService.returnEnabled, rulesEngineService.returnType, rulesEngineService.immediaterpi);
    actionProperty.setActions(JSONUtils.writeJson(returnAction));
    rule.setActionProperty(actionProperty);
    return rule;
}
```

But result is still same.
My question is when that field will be initialized? how it should be accessed from a static method , as method accessing it can not be made non static ?

Comment: Don't instantiate beans with `new`. Why does the method have to be static? Make it non-static, remove the manual object instantiation and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use @Value on static fields. Make the field non-static.

Answer (score 0):

Spring beans are singletons by default and the fields annotated with @Value will be set only once. Therefore, there is no need to define them as static fields. Besides, non-static fields are easier to mock during unit testing.

Comment: @Alexander  getting same result even after making them non -static, 
As i am using them in a static method i have created a class object and called with that , but still getting null

Comment: @user3364554, don't instantiate RulesEngineServiceImpl in the getDefaultRule method. You need to let Spring do that, otherwise it won't inject the dependencies. Can't you make the method non-static?